# Django - can't access admin login page

Tags: django

Here's the issue - I've created my project, migrated to the database django had created, and when I run the server, everything is peachy. Then I add /admin/ to my search line and it gets me to the login window.

At this point I open another command prompt window, get to the folder with my project and create a superuser. Then I try to log in using the superuser credentials, but to no avail - `This site can't be reached. 127.0.0.1 refused to connect`

Now, what's interesting is that when I run the server again, it won't even let me access the admin login site. I tried different browsers, I tried remigrating, and I tried creating new superusers (with the server both running and shut down) - and got the same result.

Eventually, it is only when I delete the superuser that I can access the admin page again. But if I create a new superuser, the story repeats itself.

I'm at my wits end, really. Any thoughts?

Comment: @ NazariiStakhovskyi check if you are running it in another terminal. If you are running on the same domain and trying to access to the same domain then the error you are getting is refering to the same thing.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean - could you elaborate, please?

Answer (score 0):

Django's development server runs on `port 8000` by default.
If you use a database other than the default sqlite3 database and the database server is running on the same port on which the development server runs then that might be the issue.
Try running the development server or the database server on different port. You can run the development server on different port using the following command:-

> python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8001

If the above solution didn't solved the problem then, try to create a superuser when the development server is not running and then restart the server and try logging in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but changing the port didn't accomplish much. Also, I use all the default settings, which means I'm using sqlite3 by default. The alternative solution you provided also doesn't help